# Why are Payments from Apple to New Zealand and Australian bank accounts wire transfers?

Tags: ios-appstore

Recent News from Apple:

> Payment processing changes for NZD and AUD currencies. February 1,
>   2019 As of February 1, 2019, all payments into bank accounts in New
>   Zealand and Australia will be wire transfers.
>
> You may need to update your banking information in iTunes Connect to
>   ensure your bank details are valid for receiving wire transfers.
>   Consult with your bank to avoid interruptions to your February payment
>   processing.
>
> In addition, the minimum monthly threshold for receiving a wire
>   transfer is the equivalent of $150 USD.

So as a NZ apple developer, why?
I'm now being charged an international processing fee.
Any advice for limiting my payments or getting around this charge?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is likely Apple's options for smaller transfers are being limited by local banking laws. What remains are the expensive SWIFT transfers you are being offered.

## Banking Sector Changes

During the last few years, money transfer organisations have stopped operating or servicing Australia because of new legislation:

- [Closing of bank accounts of money transfer operators (MTOs) is raising remittance costs](http://blogs.worldbank.org/peoplemove/closing-bank-accounts-money-transfer-operators-mtos-raising-remittance-costs)
- [Australia has been reducing the number of options for transferring funds](https://www.reuters.com/article/australia-remittances-banks-idUSL3N1632JD)

### Let Apple Know

Please contact Apple Developer and let them know this is a problem. Every piece of feedback is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No-one except Apple can tell you why they have chosen to change their policy. There can be many reasons for that.

Regarding limiting the payments: Apple automatically limits payments so that the minimum per wire transfer is $150 USD. If a single month doesn't result in $150, it is carried over to the next month, and so forth.

In regards to fees - you'll have to ask your bank for a discounted plan.